# In gouraud shading, what is the T-junction issure and how to demonstrate it with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, gouraud

I noticed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading#Problems) in the Gouraud Shading part, it said that "T-Junctions with adjoining polygons can sometimes result in visual anomalies. In general, T-Junctions should be avoided".

It seems like the T-junction is about three surfaces in picture below share edges and the point A may have different normal vector due to it belongs to different surfaces.

[image]

But what is the effect when T-junction happened and how to use OpenGL to implement it? I tried set different normal for each vertex of each rectangle and put a light in the scene, however, I didn't see anything strange in the junction point A.

Here is my code:

```
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(0, 0,1);
glVertex3f(-5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0, 1,1);
glVertex3f(5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(1, 1,1);
glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0, -1,1);
glVertex3f(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(1, 0,1);
glVertex3f(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(1, 2,1);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0, 0,1);
glVertex3f(0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0, 1, 2);
glVertex3f(-5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(1, 1, 3);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0, -2, 5);
glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(-1, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(1, -2, 0);
glVertex3f(0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

The point light is in (0, 0, 10) as well as the camera. The result below has no visual anomaly I think. Maybe normals should be kind of special?

Is there anything wrong I did? Could anyone give me some hints to make this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-Junction is bad for [Gouraud shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) and in geometry in general.

First remember that goraud shading, is a method for light interpolation used in the fixed pipeline era where light is interpolated accross the vertices, making mesh tesselation (the number and connectivity) of the vertices directly affect the shading. Having t-junction will give a sudden discontinuity in how the final interpolated color looks (keep in mind that Gouraud shading has  other problems, like under-sampling).

*Gouraud shading directly use the vertex normals unlike Phong shading, and as a note don't confuse Phong shading with Phong lighting they are different*

Note the case you are presenting is a t-junction but you won't notice any shading problem because the mesh is not tessellated enough and (it seems) you are not using any light. Try testing on a sphere with a t-junction.

Regarding geometry t-junction is considered a degenerate case. Because at that edge/polygon the geometric mesh loses consistency, you no longer have two edges connected at their ends, and you lose the polygon loop property (read: directed edges). It's usually a tricky problem to solve, a solution could be to triangulate the polygons so that the t-juction edge is now properly connected.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading

Comment: I'm not sure what you said "tessellated". Actually I used lighting. Do I need to use glutSolidSphere to draw a sphere?

Comment: @TonyLic tesselated means have more polygons; you need to Google that term, otherwise gouraud shading doesn't make much sense. also read the link I provided.

glutSolidSphere won't work, you need to create a sphere with a t-junction in order to visualize that problem.

Comment: Thanks! I mean, I know that term but I don't know how to make more tesselation in my case. Can I add more rectangle in my original case to make it tessellated because creating a T-junk sphere is kind of complex. Also, do I need to use glNormal for each vertex to give them different normal vector?

Comment: @TonyLic you said you are using lighting, actually if you look closely at your example the lighting interpolation doesn't look correct, I assume that is from the t-junction problem, the color should be white near the edges but it's inconsistent. You can create a sphere using a 3d program and import it. you can use vertex and normals arrays (also deprecated). the current non-deprecated method is called Vertex buffer objects. but could be overkill for your simple example.

Answer (score 1):

The more you deal with this situation, the more clear the problem at its core is going to become.  With one solid example and some time spent looking at it you'll probably go "aha!" and it'll click.

In theory the problem is usually described as a situation where pixels in the immediate and neighboring area of a t-vert are shaded based off of separate and sometimes different inputs (the normal at the t-vert versus the normals of neighboring verts).  You can exaggerate the problem as an illustration by setting the t-vert's normal to something very different than the neighboring verts' normals (ex. very different than their average).

In **practice** though, aside from corner cases you're usually dealing with smooth gradations of normals among vertices, so the problem is more subtle.  I view the problem in a different way because of this: as a sample data propagation issue.  The situation causes an interpolation across samples that doesn't propagate the sample data across the surface in a homogeneous way.  In your example, the t-vert light sample input isn't being propagated upward, only left/right/down.  That's one reason that t-vertices are problematic, they represent discontinuities in a mesh's network that lead to issues like this.

You can visualize it in your mind by picturing light values at each of the normal points on the surface and then thinking of what the resultant colors would be across the faces for given light locations.  Using your example but with a smoother gradation of normals, for the top face you'd see one long linear interpolation of color.  For the bottom two faces though, you'd see two linear interpolations of color driven by the t-vertex normal.  Depending on the light angle, the t-vertex normal can pick up different amounts of light than the neighboring normals.  This will drive apart the color interpolations above and below it, and you'll see a shading seam.

To illustrate with your example, I'd use one color only, adjust the normals so they form a more even distribution of relative angle (something like the set I'll throw in below), and then view it using different light locations (especially ones close to the t-vertex).

```
top left normal: [-1, 1, 1]
top right normal: [1, 1, 1]
middle left normal: [-1, 0, 1]
t-vert normal: [0, 0, 1]
middle right normal: [1, 0, 1]
bottom left normal: [-1, -1, 1]
bottom middle normal: [0, -1, 1]
bottom right normal: [1, -1, 1]
```

Because this is an issue driven by uneven propagation of sampled data--and propagation is what interpolation does--similar anomalies occur with other interpolation techniques too (like Phong shading) by the way.